# Which worker_concurrency should I have for IO-bound tasks in Celery?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, celery

I have a couple of tasks which handle API requests. The API might actually take quite a long time to respond. 5s-10s is not uncommon.

**How do I decide which value is reasonable for [`worker_concurrency`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#worker-concurrency) for IO-Bound tasks?**

The docs just state:

> The number of concurrent worker processes/threads/green threads executing tasks.
>
> If you’re doing mostly I/O you can have more processes, but if mostly CPU-bound, try to keep it close to the number of CPUs on your machine. If not set, the number of CPUs/cores on the host will be used.

What happens if I choose this number too high? Conceptually, I would expect that the OS will then switch so often between threads that (at some point) the thread switching itself becomes a high CPU load. Or is there more to it?

Reading [this](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/10/26/celery-execution-pool/), I think I should [use eventlet](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html) for IO-bound tasks:

> celery -A proj worker -P eventlet --concurreny=500

Is `worker_concurrency` the same as the `--concurrency` flag?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled apon the same issue. So as you read in [this blog post](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/10/26/celery-execution-pool/), concurrency in this situation means the number of `Greenlets` or `green threads`. So the switching between them is not the same as switching between `threads`, because each of the `green threads`

> "voluntarily or explicitly give[s] up control to one another at specified points in your code."

And

> "Greenlets are managed in application space and not in kernel space."

As stated in the blog post you read.

On the other hand switching between threads is done by the `task scheduler` of the underlying OS. So, with that in mind it is not a question which can be answered by giving you a number.

It seems to me that the number of `green threads` you use, should be tested for your scenario and the machine your celery task is executed on, in order to gain the best performance. Maybe start with 25, then 100, 500, 1000 and so on, to get a glimpse on the different times your programm takes to fully execute.

Furthermore you can test the performance of your program not just with the eventlet pool, but also the gevent pool which is pretty similar, but not the same.